# Why are --older-than and --younger-than killall options missing in RHEL/CentOS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, rhel, kill

I've experienced this issue in cleaning up scripts written by developer who were writing for Ubuntu systems, as well as [ServerFault questions like this](https://serverfault.com/questions/636406/kill-any-gs-process-thats-been-running-for-over-5m-on-centos-6-5/636475#636475).

Is there any reason the -o, -y (*--older-than and --younger-than*) options are missing from the `killall` executable of the psmisc package on EL system?

I'm interested in the historical context, because I don't usually run into many major incompatibilities with scripts/processes developed for Ubuntu. However, this is a definite conflict.

Granted, a `killall` is a heavy-handed approach to process management, but it seems as though there's a desire for a more elegant and *universal* solution than [parsing `ps` output](https://superuser.com/questions/245105/how-to-kill-all-the-processes-that-have-dates-older-than-today).

Comment: There really isn't a practical system administration question here. I think you probably meant to to ask this on [unix.se].

Comment: Actually, this *is* a practical question because I'm helping a customer port their application and related scripts from Ubuntu to CentOS in my hosting environment. It's also a distribution-related quirk; to the point where people asking the same question can receive vastly different solutions, depending on OS implementation.

Comment: The only question in your question is about a design decision made by people upstream of a particular disto. That's not a system administration question. You back that up with an interest in hitorical context.

Comment: Check your release of pmisc, it is available since release 22.9.
http://psmisc.sourceforge.net/changelog.html
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=544657

Comment: Wouldn't `pkill` fit the bill as a "more elegant and universal solution than parsing `ps` output"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would have to guess that those options came into upstream after the Fedora release that RHEL 6 was based on was frozen, since they are available in Fedora ${recent} and RHEL 7 / CentOS 7. That's only a guess, though.

Comment: I didn't have a Fedora system handy to check. EL6 was based on Fedora 12/13-ish, right? But you're certain that EL7 has this in place now?

Comment: Yes - I just checked a RHEL 7 system. At least, `man killall` has the options documented.

Comment: Yes, this is it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Every once in awhile a package like psmisc would receive some back-ported changes. This probably isn't worthy?

Comment: @ewwhite With Red Hat taking more than a year to fix _serious_ bugs, something trivial like this is probably beneath their notice.